# Intercept Promise error with vue-resource

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, vue-resource

I'd like to intercept all api responses with the code != 200 in my main.js with the following code, dispatch an action and after that, show a toast showing the error message. I'm using vue-resource and my interceptor is the following:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {
  next(function(response) {
    debugger;

    if (response.status != 200) {
      store.dispatch("errorAction", response);
    }
  });
});
```

But the code inside the callback is never reached...

And my api call is done this way. The java controller just throws an exception with the 500 error code.

```
 Vue.http
    .get(`http://${ADDRESS}/${store.state.module}/foo/exception`)
    .then(() => {}, () => {});
```

I'm new with Promises and probably i'm messing things, but i don't want to be passing an error callback to every single promise. And what if my request is as follows:

```
export function getFoo(cb) {
  Vue.http
    .get(`http://${ADDRESS}/${store.state.module}/foo`)
    .then(
      response => {
        return response.json();
      },
      () => {}
    )
    .then(foos => {
      cb(foos);
    });
}
```

I would like to get rid off () => {} and use the interceptor code to be run.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd had the same issue, so I tried to look at the documentation. Well, it is very simple, you just need to do something like this:

In main.js

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(req) {

//Here you can add some headers, if needed
req.headers.set('awesomeHeader', 'owwnt')

return function(res) {

    if( res.status == 200 || res.status == 201 || res.status == 202 ){ //Here you add the status codes that you'll work with, just like my example
        //Sucess response
    } else {
        //Every time witch an request return a status differ form the list above, you can do whatever you want, for example you can redirect the page for a new one
        window.location.href = `http://localhost:8080/#` 
        //If you want to display a notification, you need to import the component before, and then do something like it:
        Notification.success({
             title: 'error',
             message: 'Unauthorized request!',
             offset: 100
         })
    }

};
})
```

Does it answer you question? I hope it does.

Comment: i ended up using axios and its interceptors... thanks anyway!!!